# AngularJS start session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies

I want to start a new session after login is confirmed. However I got undefined cookie and it can not be done. Here is my code:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {   

    $scope.login = function() {

        $http.post("api/Login/" + $scope.email + "/"+ $scope.password).success(function(response) {          

            $scope.name = response;

            var userCookie = $cookies.get('newCookie');

            $cookies.put('newCookie', $scope.name);

        });

    };

});   
</script>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you call "starting a new session" ?

Comment: I want to make a single session after user enters correct details and clicks login button.

Comment: See Subhams answer and besides.. don't forget to rename your `$cookies` to `$cookieStore`, since you're injecting `$cookieStore` and not `$cookies`.

Comment: Isn't '$cookieStore' deprecated since 1.4 version?

Comment: Yes,$cookieStore is deprecated...so you can use $cookies instead.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is not set yet,so you got undefined cookie.
you need to set the cookies first then retrieve it.so change the order of code:

```
<script>
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
 .controller('loginController', loginController);

  function loginController($scope, $http, $cookies) {   
     $scope.login = function() {

        $http.post("api/Login/" + $scope.email + "/"+ $scope.password).success(function(response) {          

        $scope.name = response;

        $cookies.put('newCookie', $scope.name);
        var userCookie = $cookies.get('newCookie');
    });

   };

 }   
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now, but not as I thought. After login user details are displayed on the screen, but when I restart the page, it is gone. Do you have any issues?